# Highcharts dataLabels not showing in all levels of drilldown

Tags: highcharts

For some reason, the Chart's dataLabels are only displaying on bottom level of this drilldown.  The dataLabels are set for 'column'.  However, they don't display for every column rendered.

What do I need to change to get the dataLabels to display on all the levels of the drilldown?

Thanks.

See below for code and jsfiddle:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
var Drilldown = (function () {
    var chart,
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

    function setChart(name, categories, data, color, type) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
           chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'white'
        });
    }

    function buildDrillDown() {
        var stores = ['92nd Gessner', 'Annco'],
        dayparts = ['Breakfast','Lunch','Afternoon','Dinner','Late Night'],
        categories = ['Gross Sales-06/18/2013','Qty Sold-06/18/2013','Gross Sales-06/19/2013','Qty Sold-06/19/2013'],
        name = 'Gross Sales by Store Name',
        moneyLabel = {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#89A54E',
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '$'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                        }
                    },
        data = [{
                y: 9297.73,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Gross Sales-06/18/2013',
                    dataLabels: moneyLabel,
                    categories: stores,
                    data: [{
                        y: 4567.05,
                        color: colors[0],
                        drilldown: {
                            name: "Gross Sales by Daypart",
                            categories: dayparts,
                            data: [310.71,1279.32,952.65,1059.91,964.46],
                            color: colors[0]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        y: 4730.68,
                        color: colors[1],
                        drilldown: {
                            name: "Gross Sales by Daypart",
                            categories: dayparts,
                            data: [186.75,1629.05,881.34,1373.96,659.58],
                            color: colors[1]
                        },
                    }]
                }
            }];

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'drilldown_display',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Drillable Column Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view Stores. Click again to view Dayparts.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: { // Primary yAxis
          labels: {
              format: '${value}',
              style: {
                  color: '#89A54E'
              }
          },
          title: {
              text: "Gross Sales",
              style: {
                  color: '#89A54E'
              }
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#89A54E',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '$' + this.y
                    }
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(name, categories, data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    s = this.x +':<b>Gross Sales: ' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
                if (point.drilldown) {
                    s += 'Click to view '+ point.category;
                } else {
                    s += 'Click to return to the beginning';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: 'white',
            pointWidth: 75,
        }],
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                customButton: {
                    text: 'Flat Chart',
                    onclick: function () {
                      $( "#chart_display" ).show();
                      $( "#drilldown_display").hide();
                      $("#pie_display").hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }

    return {
        buildDrillDown: buildDrillDown
    };
})();

Drilldown.buildDrillDown();
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/K9fQU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code is kinda working. The data label behavior is inconsistent. When I play around your fiddle, the data label disappear for sure after I comment out `enabled: true` in `dataLabels` and run. However, if I added it back and run again, the data label shows up, hiding inside the plot area. Since you use the same color `#89A54E` for data label as the first level column, it's not quite obvious.

The reason that the data label hides inside the column is you didn't configure to handle the case when data label is [overflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow).

> How to handle data labels that flow outside the plot area. The default is justify, which aligns them inside the plot area. For columns and bars, this means it will be moved inside the bar. To display data labels outside the plot area, set crop to false and overflow to "none". Defaults to justify.

So what you need to do is, set crop to false and overflow to "none":

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        dataLabels: {
            overflow: 'none',
            crop: false,
            enabled: true,
            color: '#89A54E',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            formatter: function() {
                return '$' + this.y
            }
         },
         // other configuration
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great!  I don't think I would ever have found that.